# Is MySQL a Network Database?

Tags: android, database

I want to insert, update, show records from an android app to a database (online) which will be  installed on an android mobile.
So,my question is; which database is perfect?

1. MySQL
2. SQLite3
3. Any other

Comment: Just to make it clear what you're asking, are you looking to install the database _on the mobile phone_ or just access it from there?

Comment: You want syncing between them?

Comment: i'm not going to install database in mobile.i want to access database which will be on pc.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to use MySQL in Android. Other SQL types neither. The best way is to use a MySQL database and get the information via PHP. Encode it to JSON in PHP. You can get the Web page in Android and decode it in Android.

Comment: Thanx.Plz.Suggest me the best link.I have tried many but can't work.HttpPost may have some problem..

Answer (score 0):

> Is mysql db is network database

MySQL (like many other database servers including Postgres and Oracle) can be accessed either through a local socket or via TCP/IP. (You also mentioned SQLite, this is a file based database and does not have a network server AFAIK).

There may be libraries for Android that implement a MySQL client, but a few minutes with Google didn't turn any up for me.

Generally speaking, network access to MySQL should be limited to private networks and not end clients anyway.

If you want to access a database from a client application over a network, you are usually better off by building an HTTP based API (preferably one that is RESTful) and letting the client software connect to that. This gives you more control over what clients are allowed to do with the database.

You can build such an API in just about any language you like. If you are working with Android, you might prefer Java. My preference would be Perl. Python is a good option, etc, etc.

> which database is perfect?

Nothing is perfect. Giving a recommendation for a specific database would be drifting into "Not Constructive" territory, even if you were more specific about your requirements.